# C# Establish client-client connection in server-client model

Tags: c#, tcp, server, connection, client

I'm writing a client-server application using C# TcpListener and TcpClient. Here's what i have right now:

```
//Server
class Listener
{
  List<Client> clients; //list of clients
  TcpListener listener;

  //client accepting method
  async void Listen()
  {
    while (Listening)
    {
      Client client = new Client(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
      clients.Add(client).
      client.Exchange(); //wait for client's messages
    }
    //...
  }
}

class Client //client handling class
{
  TcpClient conn;
  public Client(TcpClient conn)
  {
    this.conn = conn;
  }
}
```

and a simple client code that just connects to server, awaits messages from it and sends message on button click, which server broadcasts to all other users. Now i want to have an ability to establish a straight connection between two clients (for private messaging and further features).

I know there's a Socket property in TcpClient and Local/RemoteEndPoint property in Socket, so server already has some information about both client hosts. I even tried to create a Socket with another clients RemoteEndPoint, but this, obviously, shouldn't work because port is in use by server. It is possible to notify both clients with required information through Server (Client class allows to play with clients individually), but how to establish TCP connection silently for both clients (i.e. no firewall messages), even for usual clients hidden under firewall and NAT-router?

Comment: If you are talking about windows firewall, then you can whitelist your application which will allow all port to communicate with it without prompt.

Comment: Y but firewall isn't the problem n.1. The main question is about how to establish straight connection between clients.

Comment: After reading the question assumed that was solved. Since your server knows about both of the clients, it can send each of them information about each other, thus allowing to open sockets to listen to each other. Checkout this example - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/

Comment: This method requires to open listening socket for one of clients, which opens a possibility for unwanted connections. I'm looking for a way (if exists) that allows to open a straight connection without listening socket.

Comment: Ok, lets clear out the requirements then. Will communication be both ways or one will be listening and other will be sending data. Maybe you can also describe the big picture of what do you try to achieve with this app?

Comment: I'm thinking of situation where two clients are in different networks, connecting to server somewhere in third place in internet. Ports aren't forwarded in those networks so listening socket seems not a good idea. New connection between clients should be two-sided, same as client-server connection is, so both clients can send data. The idea is to, for example, send files between clients ignoring server, and also this benefit in situation, where server falls down or becomes unavailable for some reason, and connection between clients still exist.

Comment: If you wish to stay in TCP layer and using socket I am afraid your only option is to establish couple of sockets. Cannot think of anything better without further investigation.

Comment: I'm looking for something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching)

Comment: Seems you figured this out yourself! Just look for libraries with this functionality.